# How to fix Permission Denial from Yahoo Mail Provider when opening an attachment?

Tags: android, permissions, android-securityexception

My application accepts certain files to be opened with the application but I've seen a couple crashes recently that say

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail.provider.MailProvider from ProcessRecord{42cb5ff0 7953:com.my.package/u0a10163} (pid=7953, uid=10163) that is not exported from uid 10147
```

In my AndroidManifest.XML I have the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.setting.permission.ALLSHARE_CAST_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Is there any permission that I might be missing for specifically Yahoo?
I'm getting the feeling that it's specifically blocked. If so is there any way I can block attachments in Yahoo from being opened with my app? Thanks

Comment: "Is there any permission that I might be missing for specifically Yahoo?" -- no. The provider is not exported. The only way you can access its contents is if the provider grants you specific rights to the `Uri`. How are you getting this `Uri`, and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I personally have never gotten the Uri. I would assume it came from the yahoo mail app when someone clicks on an attachment and sends it to my app. I use a contentresolver to get the data and with the standard Google Mail application and some others that works fine. I just copy the data into a temporary directory. This is a specific instance that is just temperamental and never before seen by myself

Comment: "when someone clicks on an attachment and sends it to my app" -- so, your activity supports `ACTION_VIEW` on a MIME type or something? "I use a contentresolver" -- just for reading, or are you also trying to get an `OutputStream`?

Comment: Yes it actively supports a MIMETYPE and i do open an inputstream and store a temporary copy of that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any permission that I might be missing for specifically Yahoo?

Not based on that error. That error indicates that Yahoo created a `ContentProvider` (`com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail.provider.MailProvider`) and screwed up their security. They should be using `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` with their `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, to allow its otherwise-not-exported provider to provide you with the file contents.

> If so is there any way I can block attachments in Yahoo from being opened with my app?

Catch the exception and point out to the user that the app that started you up is broken.

There is nothing you can put in the manifest to say "...but not Yahoo Mail".

Comment: Hahaha. Thanks for informing me on the whereabouts of the error. I'll add in that catch as it should have been there anyway to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with CommonsWare that yahoo's app data provider is not configured right, they should do one of the following:

- Declaring android:exported=true (without declaring any specific
  permissions) which will give a free access to the content provider to
  the external apps.
- Declaring temporary permission specifying
  android:grantUriPermissions=true on the provider tag in the manifest 
  and setting FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION flag on the action intent.

But in my case i found another soulution:

[Context.grantUriPermission((String toPackage, Uri uri, int modeFlags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#grantUriPermission(java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20int))

Normally this method should be called from the provider app granting access to another package, but in our case calling this method from our app:

```
grantUriPermission(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, fileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);​
```

gained access to the specified file, and we were able to open yahoo attachments.